# Ошибка в коде discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, discord

Должен выдавать карточку пользователя

```
@bot.command(name='user')
async def card_user(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
    img = Image.new('RGBA', (400, 200), '#2aff00')
    url = str(ctx.author.avatar_url)[:-10]
    
    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    response = Image.open(io.BytesIO(response.content))
    response = response.convert('RGBA')
    response = response.resize((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img.paste(response, (15, 15, 115, 115))

    idraw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    name = ctx.author.name
    tag = ctx.author.discriminator

    headline = ImageFont.truetype('calibri.ttf', size=20)
    undertext = ImageFont.truetype('calibri.ttf', size=12)

    idraw.text((145, 15), f'{name}#{tag}', font=headline)
    idraw.text((145, 50), f'ID: {ctx.author.id}', font=undertext)

    img.save('user_card.png')

    await ctx.send(file = discord.File(fp='user_card.png'))
```

А в итоге выдаёт ошибку

```
AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'avatar_url'
```

Comment: `url = str(ctx.author.avatar_url_as(format='png', size=128))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В указанной вами ошибке указано, что объект класса `Member` не имеет атрибута `avatar_url`. Поэтому попробуйте изменить `ctx.author.avatar_url` на `ctx.author.avatar.url`.

Ознакомиться с классом `Member` можно в [документации](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#member).

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command(name='user')
async def card_user(ctx, member: discord.Member):
```